# Scoring metric for multi-class cross validation

Tags: python, cross-validation, metrics, multilabel-classification

I have a DataFrame `X` in which there is a column called `target` with 10 different labels: `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`. I have a Machine Learning `model`, let's say: `model=AdaBoostClassifier()` I would like to use to fit the data and predict again the labels by doing a cross-validation process to train the model. I use two metrics for the cross-validation, the `accuracy` and the `neg_mean_squared_error` to evaluate the performance and compute the ratio: `neg_mean_squared_error/accuracy`. The lines are like:

```
model.seed = 42

outer_cv = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=1)

scoring=('accuracy', 'neg_mean_squared_error')

scores = cross_validate(model, X.drop(target,axis=1), X[target], cv=outer_cv, n_jobs=-1, scoring=scoring)

scores = abs(np.sqrt(np.mean(scores['test_neg_mean_squared_error'])*-1))/np.mean(scores['test_accuracy'])

score_description = [model,'{model}'.format(model=model.__class__.__name__),"%0.5f" % scores]
```

However, whenever I start to run, I get the following error message:
`ValueError: Samplewise metrics are not available outside of multilabel classification.`

How could I do to solve this issue with the metrics and perform the corresponding classification? Which metrics could I use to evaluate the performance of the model in the multi-label case?